# C# console app, async methods, returning before tasks complete.

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, console

Is there any way to utilize tasks/await in a console app without the application terminating upon the await statement? the following is not within the main method. It is in a separate class. Main calls it. I researched a bit and saw a post about using a manualresetevent, but when I tried inserting that logic into this class it didn't make a difference, it never gets to beyond the await. It just closes.

```
Task Taskone = Task.Run(() => (threadOne.checkData(numberArray,archivePath,dirone,dirtwo, ref missingoneList)));

Task Tasktwo = Task.Run(() => (threadTwo.checkAll(numberArray, archivePath, dirone, dirtwo, ref missingtwoList)));

Task Taskthree = Task.Run(() => (threadThree.checkCnt(numberArray, archivePath, dirone, dirtwo, ref missingthreeList)));








 await Task.WhenAll(Taskone,Tasktwo,Taskthree);

 Console.WriteLine("all tasks have completed");
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `Wait()` on the `Task` returned from your outermost async method in `Main()`.

This is usually a horrible idea, but in a console app, that's exactly how you force your code to wait for the asynchrony to complete.

You should not use `async void` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Slaks. This seemed to work. I'm not sure if I did it exactly as you mentioned. all of my tasks are called in one class method so I just put in my main a .wait() for the method that calls them, and instead of using async void I just used async Task.